# error: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

All I did was try to follow the instructions on Jekyll's site. I got an error that I don't know how to fix.

```
~ $ gem install jekyll
~ $ jekyll new my-awesome-site
~ $ cd my-awesome-site
```

When I got the error:

```
error: undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass. Use --trace to view backtrace
```

Trace results:

```
/Users/rruiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/jekyll-1.1.2/lib/jekyll/stevenson.rb:77:in `message': undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/rruiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/jekyll-1.1.2/lib/jekyll/stevenson.rb:56:in `error'
    from /Users/rruiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/jekyll-1.1.2/lib/jekyll/stevenson.rb:66:in `abort_with'
    from /Users/rruiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/jekyll-1.1.2/bin/jekyll:41:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/rruiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/commander-4.1.4/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from /Users/rruiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/commander-4.1.4/lib/commander/command.rb:180:in `call'
    from /Users/rruiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/commander-4.1.4/lib/commander/command.rb:155:in `run'
    from /Users/rruiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/commander-4.1.4/lib/commander/runner.rb:402:in `run_active_command'
    from /Users/rruiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/commander-4.1.4/lib/commander/runner.rb:78:in `run!'
    from /Users/rruiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/commander-4.1.4/lib/commander/delegates.rb:11:in `run!'
    from /Users/rruiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/commander-4.1.4/lib/commander/import.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

How do I fix this so Jekyll works?

Comment: What is your question? (TM)

Comment: @sawa Jekyll isn't working, how do I fix this so it works?

Comment: Please give more of a hint as to what's going on, what you've tried, and how it fails to solve the problem.  If you're waiting for some kind soul to read the Jekyll site (which you don't give a link to), and diagnose your problem without any further assistance from you, you may be in for a long wait.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get the same error when giving Jekyll an invalid command.

```
> jekyll foo
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/jekyll-1.1.2/lib/jekyll/stevenson.rb:77:in `message': undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)


> jekyll build
Configuration file: .../projects/my-awesome-site/_config.yml
            Source: .../projects/my-awesome-site
       Destination: .../projects/my-awesome-site/_site
      Generating... done.
```

What command are you trying to run?

`jekyll build` to build the project (`-w` to watch for changes)

`jekyll serve` to start the server